# Rails error "NoMethodError" - My first ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am absolutely and totally new to rails, so the answer is probably very simple. Here goes:

My page is generating this error

```
NoMethodError in Tasks#new
Showing app/views/tasks/new.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `tasks_path' for #
```

Here is the view:

```
<% form_for(@task) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>

    <%= f.label :description %>:
    <%= f.text_field :description %><br />

    <%= f.label :priority %>:
    <%= collection_select(:news, :priority_id, Priority.find(:all), :id, :description) %><br />

    <%= f.submit "Add Task" %>

<% end %>
```

The controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @all_tasks = Task.find(:all, :order => :id)
    end

    def new
        @task = Task.new
    end ...(more)
```

and the model:

I can't see a problem, but like I said, I'm clueless so far.
Thanks!

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :description

    belongs_to :priority
    has_and_belongs_to_many :staff
    has_and_belongs_to_many :catagory

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have

```
map.resources :tasks
```

in your routes?

Comment: Oh, you're right on. After adding that, I was able to use form_for with @task

Comment: If you've got @task = Task.new in your action, the form_for(@task) references the empty task object. :task would make your form submit to tasks/new instead of a RESTful task/ with method='post'.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the answers.

As predicted, as simple problem.

```
<% form_for(@task) do |f| %>
```

should be:

```
<% form_for(:task) do |f| %>
```

Funny how you always find the answer to a question right after you post it!
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this code:

```
@all_tasks = Task.find(:all, :order => :id)
```

You don't need to specify order by id because it's the default behavior. So this should suffice.

```
@all_tasks = Task.find(:all)
```

And this can be further condensed to the following

```
@all_tasks = Task.find.all
```

Furthermore, a rails convention is to name your instance variable @tasks

```
@tasks = Task.find.all
```

Have fun with Rails.

Comment: Thanks.
Task.find.all gives the error "Couldn't find Task without an ID"

~$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
~$ rails --version
Rails 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Please check your file name in View..
It should have extension `.html.erb` not only `.erb` ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you generated this example using the scaffold generator? Because if not it might be that you forgot to define the ressource url mapping in the routes.rb:

```
--- a/config/routes.rb
+++ b/config/routes.rb
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
+  map.resources :tasks
+
```

Don't forget to restart webrick after you've added the route!

Comment: Also checkout 'http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M000295&name=resources'

Hmm.. and @task should work.